# Set position of android spinner from database id

Tags: android, database, spinner

I have [an app](https://github.com/wholcomb/smoke_tracker/tree/add-tabs) that allows users to list habits and then create goals timers to wait until they exercise that habit again. For the goal creation activity there is a spinner of habits to choose from. I am using the following to populate it:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
  ⋮
  mHabitSelect = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.habit);

  String[] queryCols = new String[] { HabitTable.TABLE_HABIT + "." + HabitTable.COLUMN_ID, HabitTable.COLUMN_NAME };
  String[] from = new String[] { HabitTable.COLUMN_NAME };
  int[] to = new int[] { R.id.label };

  Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(MyHabitContentProvider.HABITS_URI, queryCols, null, null, null);
  SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.habit_select_row, cursor, from, to, 0);
  mHabitSelect.setAdapter(mAdapter);

  mHabitSelect.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
}
```

The `onItemSelected` method has an id parameter that seems to be the database id.

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
  long databaseId = id;
}
```

This gives me the value to save in the database, but I need a method to set the spinner to the saved habit from the database when loading the editing interface.

```
private void fillData(Uri uri) {
  String[] projection = { GoalTable.COLUMN_HABIT_ID, GoalTable.COLUMN_TIME, GoalTable.TABLE_GOAL + "." + GoalTable.COLUMN_DESCRIPTION };
  Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
  if (cursor != null) {
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    int habitId = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(GoalTable.COLUMN_HABIT_ID));
    //mHabitSelect.setSelection(habitId);
    ⋮
  }
}
```

I don't have to iterate through the results to figure out which database id is at which position in the spinner, do I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing is iterating over the items to get the position:

```
int habitId = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(GoalTable.COLUMN_HABIT_ID));
for(int pos = mAdapter.getCount(); pos >= 0; pos--) {
  if(mAdapter.getItemId(pos) == habitId) {
    mHabitSelect.setSelection(pos);
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the following situation. I suppose that you may have the same situation and you can do a similar thing:

I have an adapter that contain the items for the spinner. adapter of areas. I have Area class that I insert its objects into the adapter.

to get the position of the selected position I do:

```
int index = areasAdapter.items.indexOf(new Area(areaId, areaName));
```

then:

```
spinner.setSelection(index);
```

In your case:

```
int index = areasAdapter.items.indexOf(habitId);
spinner.setSelection(index);
```

Or the arraylist you have or anything else you have to store data in. could have something like indexOf method.

Comment: My issue is I'm using a CursorAdapter rather than an ArrayAdapter. There is no indexOf method.